# постоянные роллбэки при заполнении модели в Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Не могу понять почему это происходит.
Пробовал вводить команду и с ковычками и без...да вариаций масса была. Либо ошибка синтаксиса, а если синтаксис верен, то РОЛЛБЭК. 
прошу помощиии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: используя генератор, я создал модель с двумя полями: "text:string' и "isComplete:boolean". при попытке заполнения значениями вызывается begin а потом сразу rollback.

Comment: `.errors.to_json`

Comment: @Colibri , а можно немного подробней? я не понимаю

Comment: С примером: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors/full_messages

Comment: @Colibri , вывел сообщение (скрин по ссылке) http://skrinshoter.ru/s/270118/FmJQR3XU?a

Comment: В Rails 5.1 вы должны у `belongs_to` указывать `optional: true`, если хотите чтобы поле для связи было пустым (опциональная связь). Хотя этого поля нет на вашем скриншоте... Можно код моделей, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Андрей, у вас `Todo belongs_to Project`, я так понимаю? В пятых рельсах эта связь валидируется автоматически, соответственно при создании Todo вам нужно указать, к какому проекту он принадлежит.  
Например `Todo.create(text: 'Text', project: Project.last)` или `Todo.create(text: 'Text', project_id: Project.last.id)`.  
Если же у вас предполагается необязательная принадлежность к проекту (странно, но вдруг), то нужно указать опцию `optional: true` у связи, как и сказал Colibri

Comment: @Андрей, для того, чтобы в консоли проще было понять, почему модель не создаётся, пользуйтесь методом `create!` вместо `create` - в этом случае вы сразу увидите все ошибки валидации

Comment: @Василиса Да, есть связи между Project и Todo .добавил полe project в Todo, передал туда Project.last в итоге все равно не выходит...логику работы вроде понимаю, а как указать чтоб все корректно прошло не знаю.Скрины моделей и консоли после модификации кода ниже: http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280118/QPOWSHy1?a ; http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280118/rNgv1qrL?a ; http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280118/DN8e8WzM?a

Comment: вроде задача простая, а не могу решить уже второй день ...

Comment: Есть также пример как это в консоли должно получиться, там все экземпляры модели корректно создаются и связываются : http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280118/8oFfnzeY?a : но у меня работает по другому. не знаю в чем причина.

Comment: @Андрей, поле переименуйте из `project` в `project_id`. Для того, чтобы связь belongs_to заработала, у модели Todo должно быть поле, которое будет хранить в себе id-шник проекта, по умолчанию оно должно называться project_id. Я вас запутала своим примером, извините. Если написать `Todo.create(text: 'Text', project_id: Project.last.id)`, то в создаваемый экземпляр модели Todo в поле project_id как раз и будет передан id-шник проекта, к которому этот экземпляр должен принажлежать

Comment: @Василиса , снова такая же проблема. Пишет что не видит проджект, хотя он создан. http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280118/Kqn362SB?a

Comment: @Андрей, консоль перезагрузили? Чтобы консоль подхватила изменения ваших моделей, нужно выполнить в ней команду `reload!`

Comment: аналогичная ситуация. Projects must exist

Comment: @Андрей, только счас разглядела на скриншоте. Исправьте в модели Todo на `belongs_to: project`, в единственном числе

Comment: @Василиса о наконец то! Спасибо огромное)))

Comment: @Андрей, не за что! Очень рекомендую вам в следующий раз выкладывать код моделей и вывод ошибок прямо в вопросе, а не прикреплять скриншотами. Ну и почитать внимательно про [связи](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations) в рельсах